# How can I find all values of $\left(2^\mathrm i\right)^\mathrm i$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that $\left(2^\mathrm i\right)^\mathrm i=\exp\left(\mathrm i\log\left(2^\mathrm i\right)\right)$. But I cannot understand why the answer is $\dfrac 12\exp\left(-2k\pi\right)$.
(k:integer)

Comment: What is k in that answer?

Comment: @Shooter All integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\ln(2^i)=i\ln2+2ik\pi,\,k\in\Bbb Z$ is multi-valued, $(2^i)^i=\exp(-\ln 2-2k\pi)=\frac12\exp(-2k\pi)$.

Comment: I thought ln(2^i)=ln(e^(ilog2))=ilog2=i(ln2+i2pik)=iln2-2pik.... 
Please tell me where I made a mistake

Comment: @freddie In $w^z=\exp(z\ln w)$, we take $\ln w=\ln|w|+2ik\pi$ even if $w$ is itself written in the form $w=u^v$.

Comment: Thank you so much